# loading url from scheme not processing first time - appdelegate vs viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, appdelegate, url-scheme

My app is successfully opening and setting the parameters (from URL-scheme i.e. myApp://sometextToPrint) to a variable in the `AppDelegate` class but whenever I want to process them it fails at the first time when the app is opened from that URL. I have the app in foreground checker that calls the function for printing the parameters given, but somehow it looks like the `AppDelegate` is loaded later than the view why the view fails to print the parameters at first load.

My code looks as follow:

AppDelegate.m

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: 
[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

let geturl = url.host?.removingPercentEncoding;
UserDefaults.standard.set(geturl, forKey: "DeepLinkUrl")
return true
}
```

ViewController.m

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillEnterForeground),name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

}

@objc func appWillEnterForeground() {
    print("app on foreground")
    let user = UserDefaults.standard
    if user.url(forKey: "DeepLinkUrl") != nil {

    let str = user.value(forKey: "DeepLinkUrl") as! String
    print(str) //this is printed on the second time when I click home button and open app again
    }
}
```

For e.g., if I go to Safari and hit the following URL: myApp://printthistext, the text is not being printed. It prints when I click the home button and click the app again.

P.s. I am new at swift and don't know exactly yet which class (AppDelegate or ViewContoller) is loaded/processed first. I am already trying almost 5 hours to fix this, still keeps printing for the second time.

Comment: Well whenever the app opens appdelegate class called first

Comment: it is really strange that the ViewController is not taking the variable at the first time then...

Answer (score 1):

Copy your code from

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, 
    options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) 
    -> Bool {
```

into

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) 
    -> Bool {
```

In that method, check the `launchOptions`. If it contains the `url` key, grab that value — and return `false`.

```
if let url = launchOptions[.url] as? URL {
    let geturl = url.host?.removingPercentEncoding
    UserDefaults.standard.set(geturl, forKey: "DeepLinkUrl")
    return false
}
```

Comment: This is the solution for iOS <13.

Answer (score 0):

@SalihanPamuk I think this is due to the `appWillEnterForeground()` method. `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification` - This is the first notification posting an app is coming to the foreground.

As you have already registered an observer for listening to this notification the `appWillEnterForeground()` method will invoke before the appDelegate's

```
application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: 
[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) - method.
```

Try implementing the appDelegate's

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Do your stuffs here 
}
```

Or if you want to show any particular ViewController after opening the app using any URL setup the code for showing that ViewController inside the

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: 
[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

// implemet your code here 

}
```